# Convert Sql query to Eloquent Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I need to convert this SQL to Eloquent because i need to paginate and to retrieve a Collection, anyone can help me?

```
'SELECT n.id_norma, n.id_tipo_norma, n.texto_norma, n.fec_norma,r.cod_nodo, 
    r.articulo, t.desc_tipo_norma, n.desc_norma
    FROM normas n, rel_nodo_tem r, tipo_norma t
    WHERE r.id_norma = n.id_norma 
    AND r.id_tipo_norma = n.id_tipo_norma
    AND n.id_tipo_norma = t.id_tipo_norma 
    AND r.cod_nodo = :codNodo
    ORDER BY t.desc_tipo_norma ASC, n.fec_norma DESC, n.id_norma DESC'
```

I've tried this, but i don't have the correct result:

```
     $norms = Norm::join('rel_nodo_tem', 'rel_nodo_tem.id_norma', '=', 'normas.id_norma')
    ->where('rel_nodo_tem.id_tipo_norma', '=', 'normas.id_tipo_norma')
    ->where('rel_nodo_tem.cod_nodo', $codNodo)
    ->join('tipo_norma', 'normas.id_tipo_norma', '=', 'tipo_norma.id_tipo_norma')
    ->select('normas.id_norma','normas.id_tipo_norma','normas.texto_norma as text_norm','normas.fec_norma','normas.desc_norma', 'tipo_norma.desc_tipo_norma', 'rel_nodo_tem.cod_nodo', 'rel_nodo_tem.articulo')
    ->orderBy('tipo_norma.desc_tipo_norma', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('normas.fec_norma', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('normas.id_norma', 'desc')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Show us a sample (limit to less than five) result from the original query and the results from your attempt so that we can identify the problems.

Comment: i'm re-developing an old big system written in .asp and the only way i have to compare, is with the old output and in this case they recive less norms than i do and the type of norms i recive is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
->whereColumn('rel_nodo_tem.id_tipo_norma', '=', 'normas.id_tipo_norma')
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try and i'let you know

Comment: It works! thanks alot! but what exactly is the behaviour here?

Comment: You have to explicitly tell Laravel that `normas.id_tipo_norma` isn't a string value, but a column name.

Comment: I replaced my answer with a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this query :

```
 $norms = DB::table('normas')
        ->leftJoin('rel_nodo_tem','normas.id_norma','=','rel_nodo_tem.id_norma')
        ->leftJoin('tipo_norma', 'normas.id_tipo_norma', '=', 'tipo_norma.id_tipo_norma')
        ->where('rel_nodo_tem.id_tipo_norma', '=', 'normas.id_tipo_norma')
        ->where('rel_nodo_tem.cod_nodo', $codNodo)
        ->select('normas.id_norma','normas.id_tipo_norma','normas.texto_norma as text_norm','normas.fec_norma','normas.desc_norma', 'tipo_norma.desc_tipo_norma', 'rel_nodo_tem.cod_nodo', 'rel_nodo_tem.articulo')
        ->orderBy('tipo_norma.desc_tipo_norma', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('normas.fec_norma', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('normas.id_norma', 'desc')
        ->paginate(20);
```